# Derivation of Wigner Function of cosine with phase

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, wigner-transform

The Wigner Function of $x(t)$ is

$$ W(t,f) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int x\Big(t+\frac{\tau}{2}\Big)x^*\Big(t-\frac{\tau}{2}\Big) e^{-j2\pi f\tau}\;d\tau $$

I know how to get the $W(t,f)$ of $$x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_i t)$$ which is

$$[\delta(f+f_i)+\delta(f-f_i) + 2\delta(f) \cos(4 \pi f_i t)].$$

However, I found a difficulty in deriving the cosine when the phase $\theta$ is included, $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_i t + \theta)$.

Comment: The wigner function of $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_i t+\theta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\cos(2\pi f_i t + \theta) = 
  \cos(2\pi f_i (t + \theta/2\pi f_i)= x(\tilde t), \\ \hbox{where}~~\tilde t\equiv  t + \theta/2\pi f_i.  $$

So, just plug into your expression for *x(t)*, if you trust and understand it.

Comment: So I just need to replace the $t$ with this new one that includes the phase?

Comment: Yes. Isn't it evident?

Comment: Great! I was just thinking that the two impulses will also be affected by the phase but I realized maybe not.